# Unix equivalent of smart folders

Tags: filesystems, symlink, directory-structure

What I want to do is present a directory, the contents of which are sourced from a series of other directories on the file system. It would be like a soft-link, only a link to multiple directories at once, rather than just one.

The directory might be considered read-only - or, if updates to a file are made, it would be good if those updates occurred in the source-file (i.e. the directory is a "window" into a number of locations on the file-system)

If a new file is created in this 'pseudo' directory, it should either be dropped into some default location, or rejected altogether.

Similar functionality exists in Windows (under the name libraries) and OSX (smart folders) - is there any Unix equivalent?

Comment: What do you mean by _Unix_? OS/X (at least some versions) is a certified Unix, Linux-based systems currently are not. Any particular other Unix you had in mind?

Comment: Good point - I suppose any 'nix distribution that you might expect to interface with via a command-line. I tend to run Debian or Ubuntu, but I'd be interested in anything similarly flavoured so that should I port/share/distribute my application I can consider different methods of providing this kind of functionality across platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not available as part of standard Unix or a graphical Linux interface.

Linux system administrators can use overlayfs.  Actually one of the most important uses is to allow modifications to a running LiveCD system, e.g. installing extra packages.

There are also equivalents in FUSE, which can be used on Linux without root privileges.  There will be additional limitations from FUSE but it could work well for the same cases as the features you mentioned.  unionfs-fuse appears to be available in ubuntu.  ("union mount" is an older term for the concept).

Comment: Thanks this looks like a good option - I tend to run Debian or Ubuntu, so will look into this - I've been googling/researching around union mounts after your answer, and there seems to be something called [aufs](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/05/linux-aufs/) which might apply here. Thanks for the help!

Comment: ah.  overlayfs is in linux mainline kernels now (the other kernel union mounts had to be patched in).  It looks like Debian stable is still reliant on aufs though.

Answer (score -1):

Your question have been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423320/can-i-symlink-multiple-directories-into-one).

I've modified Mr. paxdiablo's script to suit your problem:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
    mkdir nu
    for i in dir1/* dir2/* dir3/*; do
        ln -s $i nu/$(basename $i)
    done
    mv smartdir ole
    mv nu smartdir
    rm -rf ole
done
```

So `dir1`, `dir2`, `dir3` are directories you want to symlink to, and `smartdir` is the 'smart folder'. Just run this as a startup. Note that there shouldn't be files or folder in the `dir{1, 2, 3}`, or you'll get f**ked (well, so you may call the script *stupid folders* maker instead).

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I can see this (or something like this) being useful at some point, but prefer something that doesn't require refreshing - however, if any of the options in sourcejedi's answer aren't available in a particular distribution, this might form the basis of a working go-to. Thankyou.